# Real-time server updates for native mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, windows, real-time, native

At the moment I am trying to figure out what my options are regarding real-time server updates for native apps (Android, iOS and Windows Mobile). Everywhere I see real-time web apps but I do not require a browser in my app. I have read SignalR and the additional libraries for Android (SignalA) and iOS (objectiveC). But I was wandering wether anyone has suggestions about this topic.

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for push notifications. You can find additional details for iOS apps [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)
Android SDK too comes with such a service. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for additional details.

In case if you are looking for a common service. There are several third party vendors who offer that too. check [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) that too. (I am not promoting them but just to provide all details )

However, I would recommend you to use TCP sockets if you are sending high amount of data (generally in real time data that is the case).

Also push notifications are not reliable. User may or may not get them. There is not such guarantee. For something like RSS feed I would suggest polling.

Comment: We are looking to send and recieve data to and from a server. For example, like the MSN status, person 1 goes offline, this is send to a server, the server then sends this status update to all clients connected to this person. The only difference now is that it has to work on desktop, native app for Android, iOS, windows phone and other applications without any delay.

Comment: Yes your server is common for all of them. The information which I have provided you is about settings for Client (android and iOS). I will suggest you to use TCP sockets and ask your app to connect to those sockets.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I used GCM with push notifications.

It is fit for me that make my application real-time.

And it can save your battery, because of your

application don't pull the data from the server every ... sec.

For the example of GCM [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) is a good example to start.

Comment: Thank you for awnsering my question and making a suggestion. I have looked into Google Cloud Messaging but we dont want a google server to handle our messages and it is only for android, what we are looking for is 1 solution.